# Java-17 Spring Webflux - Java Streaming elements inside arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, spring-webflux

Currently am working on Java-17 Spring Webflux and Spring Data JPA

basically am retrieving data from DB through repository class and doing summing, averaging calculations inn serviceImpl class. So, the flow goes like below,

**Entity Class**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class EmployeeDO implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private LocalDate date;

    @Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
    private int deptId;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_DAYS")
    private String numberOfDays;

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_HOURS")
    private String totalHours;

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_MANPOWER")
    private String totalManpower;

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_WAGES")
    private String totalWages;

    @Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_ITEMS")
    private String numberOfItems;
```

** Repository Class **

```
@Query("FROM EmployeeDO e WHERE e.deptId =:deptId and e.date =:date ORDER BY e.date ASC")
List<EmployeeDO> getEmployeeRec(@Param("deptId") int deptId,
@Param("date") int date);
```

** Service Impl class **

```
var empList = employeeDao.getEmployeeRec(100, '2023-08-14');
var avgNumberOdDays = empList.stream().mapToDouble(empList::getNumberOfDays)
.sum();
var avgTotalHours = empList.stream().mapToDouble(empList::getTotalHours)
.average();
var avgTotalManpower = empList.stream().mapToDouble(empList::getTotalManpower)
.sum();
var avgTotakwages = empList.stream().mapToDouble(empList::getTotalWages)
.average();
```

Need to avoid Streaming to each element and Streaming should be more efficient way. Any best approach's from Java or Webflux to Stream whole ArrayList one time and doing the calculation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some NoSQL databases, relational databases are usually not reactive. You can call `Flux.fromIterable`, but that still gives you a list as intermediate. You could try letting the method return `Stream<EmployeeDO>` instead of `List<EmployeeDO>` and call `Flux.fromStream`, but depending on the database implementation this may not give any performance improvements (it may collect to a list internally).

There are some wrappers that let you return `Mono<EmployeeDO>` and `Flux<EmployeeDO>` directly from the repository, but as long as the database itself is not reactive this will still not be fully reactive.

As for the multiple stream operations, you should consider a custom collector that collects all information in one go. `IntSummaryStatistics` is an example where the JDK itself has built-in support, but it's not that hard to create a class + collector like that yourself.